# Experiencing Persistent Prior Entries,Clearing on Click

Tags: javascript, codemirror, codemirror-modes, ui-codemirror, codemirror-6

In a .NET MVC project, using the Code Mirror library in JavaScript, I encountered the following issue:

.NET Framework version - 4.5
Code Mirror version - 5.63.1

1.Reopening the editor reveals previous data persisting without clearing.
2.Clicking on the editor removes previously entered data.
3.Below is the code snippet for clearing CodeMirror instances:
[image: HTML]
[image: To clear instances]
Implementation of code mirror:
[image: Initialization of code mirror]

I’m seeking assistance in resolving this issue.